# I need some pointers on performing a simple calculation in C#

Tags: c#

I am moving from VB.Net to C#. I am a complete beginner in C#.

I an trying to code a simple calculation in a function. The user inputs 3 values, a calculation is performed, and returns an answer. I have no idea of where to start.

I have trolled the forums, referenced a book, etc. I am getting bogged down with attributes (extern, partial, static, etc) and other things around it.

In VB.Net I would do this:

```
 Function TestCalc(MilliAmps As String, PV_High As String, PV_Low As String)

    Dim MilliAmps_dbl As Double
    Dim PV_High_dbl As Double
    Dim PV_Low_dbl As Double
    Dim PV_Value_dbl As Double
    Dim PV_Value_str As String


    MilliAmps_dbl = CDbl(MilliAmps)
    PV_High_dbl = CDbl(PV_High)
    PV_Low_dbl = CDbl(PV_Low)

    PV_Value_dbl = (((MilliAmps_dbl - 4) / 16) * (PV_High_dbl - PV_Low_dbl)) + PV_Low_dbl


    PV_Value_str = CStr(PV_Value_dbl)

    Return PV_Value_str

End Function
```

The code takes 3 string inputs from text boxes, converts them to real values, performs the calculation and returns a string value as an answer.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, as I am clueless at the stage, of how to do it in C#.

Thanks

Comment: What are CBdl() and CStr()?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+vb.net+to+c%23+online

Comment: Search this site for `[c#] double.tryparse`. That should give you a place to start. You should also search for a C# tutorial using Google. This is very basic.

Comment: There is an [online code converter available.](https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/)  It's also available as an add-on for Visual Studio; you can get it from the Visual Studio Marketplace as the Code Converter C# to/from VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code sample, converted to C# with the Code Converter C#to/from VB.NET, with one minor addition (the return value is declared as string):

```
    public string TestCalc(string MilliAmps, string PV_High, string PV_Low)
    {
        double MilliAmps_dbl;
        double PV_High_dbl;
        double PV_Low_dbl;
        double PV_Value_dbl;
        string PV_Value_str;


        MilliAmps_dbl = System.Convert.ToDouble(MilliAmps);
        PV_High_dbl = System.Convert.ToDouble(PV_High);
        PV_Low_dbl = System.Convert.ToDouble(PV_Low);

        PV_Value_dbl = (((MilliAmps_dbl - (double)4) / (double)16) * (PV_High_dbl - PV_Low_dbl)) + PV_Low_dbl;


        PV_Value_str = System.Convert.ToString(PV_Value_dbl);

        return PV_Value_str;
    }
```

Comment: mmm, this wouldn't compile, also even if it did its suspect to return a string from this anyway, also the correct way to convert user input is the TryParse methods

Comment: Now it compiles. Yes, I'd use the TryParse methods myself, or have doubles as the parameters.